# Retrieve selected elements in GeckoWebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, geckofx

I am using GeckoFX version 1.9.1.0 with C#.NET. I have a placed a GeckoWebBrowser Component (geckoWebBrowser1) and a Button (button1) in a form and have navigated the browser to a page. Some text in the page can be selected. This text is composed of one or more DOM elements.
When button1 is clicked, I want to retrieve the DOM elements that compose the selected text in the page and give an id to one of those elements and save add these ids to a list (in C# space).
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geckoWebBrowser.Window.Selection` is an accessor for a `GeckoSelection` object which contains everything you need. You can get the nodes & offset where selection starts and ends, or you can get a range of all elements spanned by the selection.